# Versioning entity relations with PHP in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm

I'm in the process of designing a system that stores entities and their relations over time.

Each entity has properties, each property should be versioned, so when a property of the entity changes, a new history state gets added. The complexity comes with the fact that I also need to version the relations between the separate entites. For example: when entity `A` moves from parent `X` to parent `Y`, the relation of both entities also gets a new history state.

I'm looking for advice on how to design this on a lower level - are there any design patterns available for this sort of thing, or any other best practices/proven methods?

I'm building this in PHP with a PostgreSQL database, optionally using Doctrine as the ORM/DBAL.

Comment: I've always built things like this with triggers. You need to think pretty hard about concurrency issues, but you need to do that no matter what level you're working at. Often all you need is the odd `SELECT .. FOR SHARE` on a parent before you capture things about parent and child objects.

Comment: take a look here before: https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into the `table_log` extension (https://github.com/psoo/table_log) for this.  It does require compiling but it has the advantage of allowing you to restore tables to a previous state, audit changes, etc.

One important detail here is that the history changes are stored in other tables, not your main tables, so you think of it as current data plus external audit trails.  If you need to merge them for a query, you could create a view.